# Pass form data to redirected page - javascript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
             <div class="box-wrapper">
                <form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/formmail/FormMail.pl">
                    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="mail123@gmail.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Contact Form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://127.0.0.1/contact.html?formsubmit=success">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" required="">
                    <input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="number" required="">
                    <input name="service" list="services" placeholder="What service you need?" required>
                    <datalist id="services">
                        <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
                        <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
                        <option value="UI/UX Design">UI/UX Design</option>
                        <option value="Digita Marketing">Digital Mareketing</option>
                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    </datalist>
                    <textarea placeholder="Additonal detail" name="details" required=""></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-btn" onclick="thanksMsg()"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
                </form>
                <div id="thanksmsg"></div>
            </div>
```

This is my html code.I'm passing form data to my mail after submit. and redirecting to "http://127.0.0.1/contact.html?formsubmit=success". On this page i display thanks msg using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        var text = $('#form').find('input[name="name"]').val();
        if(url == 'http://127.0.0.1:8887/contact.html?formsubmit=success'){
            var name = $('#form').find('input[name="name"]').val();
            $('#thanksmsg').append('<p>Hi'+text+', Thanks for reaching us out. <br>We will get back to you shortly </p><div><a class="cta-btn">Back to home</a><a class="cta-btn">View our Portfolio<a></div>');
            $('form').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

here in thanks msg i wanted to show the name entered in input field. but as it gets redirected it doesn't appear. how to display the name?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cookies. At the form submit, write something like `$.cookie('name', name)`. To recover you call `$.cookie('name')`.
I'm not sure if it'll work, because in some cases the cookies are erased, but is easy to try.